# why I use the static library to compile and link is corrent while the dynamic library is wrong for am ace demo?

Tags: c++, ace

my gcc/g++ version is 4.1.2 , ACE-6.10 in CentOS 5.10 and I make the ACE Library with *static_libs=1*  option to get the static library, after make and make install ,I get such libraries such as libACE.so , libACE.a and so on, and then I write following code to test, The codes shows as follow:

```
#include <ace/Log_Msg.h>
#include <ace/OS_main.h>

using namespace std;

int ACE_TMAIN(int argc, ACE_TCHAR *argv[])
{
    ACE_DEBUG( (LM_DEBUG, ACE_TEXT("Hello World!\n") ) );
    return 0;
}
```

then I use the following two method to compile and link :

method 1:

```
 g++ -p -o acetest acetest.cpp  /usr/local/src/ACE_wrappers/lib/libACE.a -I$ACE_ROOT -I$ACE_ROOT/ace -pthread  -ldl -lrt
```

method 2:

```
[root@localhost testCode]# g++ -p -o acetest acetest.cpp  -L/usr/local/src/ACE_wrappers/lib -lACE -I$ACE_ROOT -I$ACE_ROOT/ace -pthread  -ldl -lrt
/tmp/cc0eKwlC.o: In function `main':
acetest.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `ACE_Log_Msg::last_error_adapter()'
acetest.cpp:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `ACE_Log_Msg::instance()'
acetest.cpp:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `ACE_Log_Msg::conditional_set(char const*, int, int, int)'
acetest.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `ACE_Log_Msg::log(ACE_Log_Priority, char const*, ...)'
collect2: ld 返回 1
```

And it comes to the question, the method 1 to use static library is corrent, why method 2,which uses the dynamic library, is wrong?

hunger for the answer, thanks all;

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your application you should add the `-DACE_AS_STATIC_LIBS` flag to the compiler to indicate that you want to link statically with ACE

Comment: thanks, but the way I link with static library in the method 1 is corrent to get the executable file. The problem I'm trapped in is when I use the dynamic library ,which shows as method 2 above, to link is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `no_hidden_visibility=1` to your `platform_macros.GNU` file. I believe ACE builds its shared libraries with symbols hidden by default.

See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) for the benefits this can provide. However, it doesn't seem to work well when mixing static and dynamic libraries. If anyone has more info on why that is, feel free to chime in.